# What are the best ways to to generate hash of source code?

Tags: .net, vb.net, hash, integrity

I will be releasing the source code of a Windows .net application that I currently charge for support for. I will no longer be making additional changes to it, but will continue to support my builds.

My idea is to have the code generate a hash code that can be displayed in the application so that I can determine if the code has been altered, thus ending my support of that build.

How do I go about generating a hash of the source code?

Note: I know any tampering can be hidden when you have control of the source code, but I'm going to assume that the users won't be digging too deep into manipulating this feature.

Comment: What about generating a CRC on the .exe when the program starts. I hope that helps.

Comment: I don't understand your statement, "I'm going to assume that the users won't be digging too deep into manipulating this feature." If you're worried about the code being modified, then you must think that the users are willing to dig deep enough to modify the code. What makes you think they won't also manipulate the hash feature?

Comment: Why not ignore the hash entirely in your open source version and put it only in your builds? That way, if the code that generates the hash is missing, you know if it's your build or not (of course you'd need some way to interface with it so that you can check it). Beware of decompilers though.

Comment: Otherwise another (and more robust) alternative would be to sign your executable with a code signing certificate. It doesn't matter if it's self-signed or CA-signed as you'll be using it to verify the integrity yourself.

Comment: @JimMischel It's a fairly large application, with only a few dozen clients using it. I won't be advertising the hash feature. I'm hoping to use it more in a case of "something doesn't smell right" with your support request, and then have them reveal the hash to verify. Just knowing my users, I'm not too concerned about them making changes at all, but I just want something quick and easy to have my back, even if I know it's not fool proof

Comment: @VisualVincent I like your idea of including it in my builds, and excluding it from the source code

Answer (score 0):

You could use the build-in functionality. Assembly modules are already hashed, you could simply put a multi-line textbox in the about dialog and write out the moduls versions (which are in reality some 128-bit hashes):

```
Imports System
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports System.IO

Public Class CompilationInfo

    Public Shared Function GetModuleInfo() As String
        'TODO: Add code that ensures all relevant modules are loaded <<<
        Dim myResult As New StringWriter()
        For Each myInfo As (ModuleName As String, ID As Guid) In ModuleIdentifiers()
            myResult.WriteLine($"{myInfo.ID}: {myInfo.ModuleName}")
        Next
        Return myResult.ToString()
    End Function

    Private Shared Iterator Function ModuleIdentifiers() As IEnumerable(Of (ModuleName As String, ID As Guid))
        For Each myAssembly In AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
            For Each myModule As System.Reflection.Module In myAssembly.GetModules()
                Yield (myModule.FullyQualifiedName, myModule.ModuleVersionId)
            Next
        Next
    End Function

End Class
```

In the about dialog, you simply assign the result:

```
myCompilationInfoTxt.Text = CompilationInfo.GetModuleInfo()
```

- As a pre-publish step you store this output in a database.
- To compare whether the customer tampered something, you write a little tool that compares a given string against the stored database values (only the GUIDs).
- You ask the customer to send you the list of loaded modules from the about dialog and run them through your tool.
- The module pathes are only as a hint to know what module was tampered with.